# Three.js Multi-tile UV

Tags: three.js

Does Three.js support Multi-tile UV?

I have a mesh with 2 sets of uvs exported from maya as .json file. I tried using MultiMaterial by defining 2 different material with 2 different set of textures like so:

```
var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({//side

        color: 0xffffff,
        map: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Side_DiffMap),
        normalMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Side_NormalMap),
        normalScale: new THREE.Vector3(1, 1),       
        displacementMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Side_DisplacementMap),
        aoMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Side_AOMap),
        specularMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Side_SMap),

    });

var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({//top

        color: 0xffffff,
        map: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Top_DiffMap),
        normalMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Top_NormalMap),
        normalScale: new THREE.Vector3(1, 1),       
        displacementMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Top_DisplacementMap),
        aoMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Top_AOMap),    
        specularMap: textureLoader.load(topINF_TopSide_Top_SMap),
    });

materials.push(material1);
materials.push(material2);
```

then I created my mesh as follows

```
var mesh = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry,  [material2, material1]);
mesh.children[0].material.transparent = true;
mesh.children[0].material.opacity = 0.5;
```

However it seems that it uses only the first set of uvs on the mesh since the textures appear on top of each others.

Here is the results I get in maya which I was hoping for

[maya results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXNSM.png)

And here is what I get from Three.js

[Threejs results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0QSU.png)

Comment: taken from `createMultiMaterialObject` [HERE](https://threejs.org/docs/api/extras/SceneUtils.html). Creates an new Object3D an new mesh for each material defined in materials. Beware that this is not the same as MultiMaterial which defines multiple material for 1 mesh.
This is mostly useful for object that need a material and a wireframe implementation.

Comment: I've checked the documentation but even when I try this: `mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));`, it gives me the same results. I just want to find a way in three.js to have multiple UVs so that my textures are mapped properly. Thank u though